# Show native toast in Phonegap Application in android

Tags: android, cordova, toast

How to show native Toast in Phonegap version 3.5 application in android.can we create any class in Android Application to show Toast in Phonegap Application

Comment: You can use a plugin, like [this one](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin), to show a native toast.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom(
    "Server error",
    function(a) {
        console.log('toast success: ' + a)
    }, 
    function(b) {
        console.log('toast error: ' + b)
});
```